# Dashboards for fields using comma separated values?

Tags: dashboard

I'm storing comma separated values in a couple fields. I'd like to generate a dashboard based on these values, and I'm wondering if there's a way to get these distinct values?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a graph that uses the values inside those fields? So let's say, for example, one field contains "3,5,7,11,1", you want to show a graph with the values 3, 5, 7, 11 and 1?

Comment: @SanderdeJong Yes, although I want the graph to span multiple fields. So if I have another field with "89, 13, 2", I want a graph displaying 3, 5, 7, 11, 1, 89, 13, and 2.